# Reference InfoPath field in edit.aspx InfoPath web part

Tags: web-part, infopath, javascript, email, edit-form

I have a colleague I'm trying to help. He has a list on a SharePoint site. He modified said list's web part with InfoPath. Upon creating a new item, the item is saved as well as emailed to a 3rd party as an active form view. Now, what he wants is a hyperlink in this form in the email that will open the item in in location on SharePoint in the browser to edit.

This means having the url to the EditForm.aspx page (or in the case of a form edited in InfoPath the editifs.aspx page) with all the extra details attached identifying the item, which is in the lines of:

> editifs.aspx?List=f7ccb91b%2D7d86%2D4c4b%2D9db5%2D3a63d916e259&ID=4&ContentTypeId=0x010015D033B7D1DD0742A9B504B5837BA31F&IsDlg=1

Now, previously, if this was still the default web part I would have used JavaScript in the EditForm.aspx to get the page url and set it to a field in the web part. I have not yet however figured out how to reference the fields in the InfoPath type web part.

Recently (while i was typing this) I also realized that would not work, as the form is emailed to the 3rd party recipient from the InfoPath submit rules. This means we want the url inside the form, and not in the list item or the .aspx page per se. I have confirmed from my colleague that yes, he does indeed want the form to be displayed in the email and wants a link to the edit page in this form.

I (and by association my colleague) would greatly appreciate any thoughts on how we could proceed to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem by placing the following formula as the default value on a field:

```
concat(SharePointListUrl(), "Item/editifs.aspx?ID=", ID)
```

This identifies the current item in the list by the ID assigned by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

> Reference InfoPath field in edit.aspx InfoPath web part

I believe you are confusing in your post:

- edit.aspx with EditForm.aspx
- EditForm.aspx with editifs.aspx
- Infopath Web Part with Web Part page
- and sharepoint list/library fields with sharepoint list/library items

That is, it is possible to reference by URL the item but not the field.
And in case of Infopath Form Web Part ASPX page, it is conceptually all the same as for any other Web Part ASPX page.
And external referencing by URLs has nothing to do with Infopath. Infopath forms are just XML data for generating forms and collecting data in them by external apps of MS Office, Sharepoint Server, etc.

Most probable I misunderstood the terminology and English of your question.   Sorry for this. 
But, in any case, I believe you would get a better response if you edit your post.